# C#: doing math on weird formatted dateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime, logic

I've got some Date-timestamps reading in from a log file, the problem is that the log file records these timestamps weirdly, for example:

"2020061515141112" is how its in the file, which represents "2020 06/15 15:14:11.12"

The issue I'm running into is that I've got loglines for start events and end events, and I need to parse out time period between them.

My question is:
in a C# application, how can I parse the strings (yyyyMMddHHmmssff) into a format that can be used by DateTime to perform a `<DateTime.Subtract>` between them? I'm not super familiar with Date-times and having a hard time getting Visual Studio to agree with the below:

```
DateTime aDT = DateTime.Parse(aLogDate,"yyyyMddHHmmssff",System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

which meets the expected format of (string,IFormatProvider,DateTimeStyle) but arguments are invalid (is it the format provider?)

EDIT: we were able to modify the format the Log prints (sort of) to retain leading zeros in their dateTimes, so this is no longer an issue, above still in question)

Comment: You're pretty much screwed as not forcing everything to 2 digits with leading zeros means you can have ambiguous timestamps like is "202011115141112" January 11th or November 1st.  You'd have to format the string into something that can be parsed by either adding missing leading zeros or delimiters (what the "genius" should have done in the first place)

Comment: yeah... I figured, but for this scenario we are only investigating dateTimes for June10-June13 so I will be able to "get by" for our diagnostics

Comment: @Medic3000 it could get worst `202011111111` is that `2020 1/1 11:11:11` or `2020 1/11 1:11:11` or  `2020 11/1 1:11:11`

Comment: @Franck we have found a setting in the software that provides the logs that allows the toggling of leading zeros for Month/Hour/Day so we now have a consistent yyyyMMddHHmmssff output to log. with this in mind the original question is still in play

Comment: So assuming you have your 2 timestamps in DateTime form, say t1 and t2, you can subtract t1 from t2, and you get a TimeSpan, say d = t2 - t1.   d can then be displayed as d.ToString("\\HH\\mm\\ss.ff") or as you would like it.

Comment: @MarcG the issue was I didnt know how to convert a string to a timestamp. calculating timespan is simply string timeSpan = t2.subtract(t1).toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime aDt = DateTime.ParseExact(aLogDate, "yyyyMMddHHmmssff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Help from a friend came first. Heres what I wanted, people were getting to caught up on details, should have made question more concise to begin with

Comment: "2020 06/15 15:14:11.12" the format you suggest would work.  You don't need to give it a format if you use DateTime.Parse i.o. DateTime.ParseExact.